# How many zones does Sonic Mania have, in total?

Tags: sonic-mania

The ones I have noted are:

- GHZ: Green Hill (from Sonic 1)
- CPZ: Chemical Plant (from Sonic 2)
- SPZ: Studiopolis
- FBZ: Flying Battery (from Sonic 3&K)
- PGZ: Press Garden
- SSZ: Stardust Speedway
- HCZ: Hydrocity (from Sonic 3&K)
- MSZ: Mirage Saloon
- LRZ: Lava Reef (from Sonic 3&K)
- MMZ: Metalic Madness
- OOZ: Oil Ocean (from Sonic 2)
- TMZ: Titanic Monarch

I haven't been able to progress farther. Are there hidden zones? What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean you haven't been able to progress further? You beat the game. (Beating it with all 7 Chaos Emeralds gives you the "good" ending, but you still beat it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sonic Mania has 13 different zones.** (8 remastered, 5 new).

1. [**Green Hill Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Hill_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (GHZ) - Sonic 1
2. [**Chemical Plant Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Chemical_Plant_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (CPZ) - Sonic 2
3. [**Studiopolis Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Studiopolis_Zone) (SPZ)
4. [**Flying Battery Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Battery_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (FBZ) - Sonic & Knuckles
5. [**Press Garden Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Press_Garden_Zone) (PGZ)
6. [**Stardust Speedway Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Stardust_Speedway_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (SSZ) - Sonic CD
7. [**Hydrocity Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Hydrocity_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (HCZ) - Sonic 3
8. [**Mirage Saloon Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Mirage_Saloon_Zone) (MSZ)
9. [**Oil Ocean Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Oil_Ocean_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (OOZ) - Sonic 2
10. [**Lava Reef Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Reef_Zone_(Sonic_Mania)) (LRZ) - Sonic & Knuckles
11. [**Metallic Madness Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Metallic_Madness_Zone) (MMZ) - Sonic CD
12. [**Titanic Monarch Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Titanic_Monarch_Zone) (TMZ)
13. [**Egg Reverie Zone**](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Egg_Reverie_Zone)

Egg Reverie Zone is the thirteenth and true final Zone in Sonic Mania. It can only be accessed while playing as Sonic after collecting all 7 Chaos Emeralds.

You can view all of the available zones through the unlockable level select menu in Debug Mode.

[image: Sonic Mania Level Select]

***Source***: [Sonic News Network - Sonic Mania Zones](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_Mania#Zones)

Answer (score -5):

#### All of Sonic Mania's zones are here:

- Starlight Zone [Sonic 1]
- Emerald hill Zone [Sonic 2, Can only be found when you add Sonic and Knuckles on Sonic 2]
- Studiopolis Zone
- Sandopolis Zone [Sonic and Knuckles]
- Press garden Zone
- Palm tree panic Zone [Sonic CD]
- Ice Cap Zone [Sonic 3]
- Mirage Saloon Zone
- Metropolis Zone [Sonic 2]
- Hidden Palace Zone [Sonic 3 version]
- Collision Chaos Zone [Sonic CD]
- Titanic Monarch Zone
- Egg Reverie Zone

Comment: What's your source? The two answers seem to differ